# .NET Singleton Long Running Stopwatch Instance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, stopwatch

What are the implications of a having a long running single instance of Stopwatch?

E.g.

```
public static Stopwatch Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

And then all over the place use `Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks`?

I am trying to avoid creating additional GC pressure on Hot Paths and be able to leave most of the diagnostics code in there without `#IF` wrappers.

Comment: Nothing special.  The underlying hardware counter that supplies Stopwatch with samples is always ticking, whether you use Stopwatch or not.  It is not calibrated like DateTime.UtcNow so if you use it for days on end then you might see discrepancies with the regular clock.  No GC load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stop watching actually doesn't do anything functional when running, and only stores values on start and finish and converts it to a timespan, which in turn can store a max value of 10675199.02:48:05.4775807, or 10,675,199 days.

The source code is extremely trivial, as you can see here

[Stopwatch Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs)

The overhead of having this running in a singleton is negligible